# CSS3 transitions not working on button

Tags: css, css-transitions

I have a relatively complex button that I'm styling with CSS3, it looks and behaves as I intended apart from the transitions are not working. It should fade on hover etc but it's just not working, tested in moz opera and chrome, no luck.

Here's a link to a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/dsyne/DpsuN/1/

Any help would be appreciated, i've tried many different things. Re-ordering the stack for instance. I'm not sure if the ordering is important with transitions ?

edit:wrong link sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gradients don't support transitions directly yet. You should define your background colors then use a pure alpha gradient that is the same across states to add shading.

Comment: do you mean pure alpha like this: 'background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,102,153,0.8), rgba(0,102,153, 1));' the transition seems to work with a gradient on the normal state but not when i add gradients to the hover/focus/active states.

Comment: Got it to work finally using a white gradient changing alpha only. Seems only to work with the exact same gradient values on all states. also something to note is that it wont work unless background color is declared underneath the gradients in the css. Thank you very much for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Yes, the joys of web dev on the edge! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use id to specify transition property instead of class. Worked for me!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).